# write delete query for following in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am having a situation in my MySQL database table of row repeating
So I got this

```
DELETE from table1
USING table1, table1 as vtable
WHERE (NOT table1.ID=vtable.ID)
AND (table1.field_name=vtable.field_name)
```

Where `table1` is the table and `vtable` is a virtual table

How should I write that in **Zend Framework**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zend_Db_Select` supports the `USING` clause, but I think it's not supported by the `Zend_Db_Adapter` `delete()` method.

A possible alternative would be passing the SQL expression directly to the connection (if you are using the `pdo_mysql` adapter, it will be a [PDO object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)):

> $db->getConnection()->exec($sqlExpression);

(**IMPORTANT**: Make sure you quote properly all the identifiers and values in the SQL sentence, `Zend_Db_Adapter` has some [extensive documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html) about this).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Pang ! I have just replaced the dead link. Apparently the documentation URL was moved since I wrote this answer 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but this is how to use a basic delete in Zend:

```
$db->delete('table1', array('ID != ?' => $otherID, 'field_name = ?' => $otherFieldName));
```

Is this what you are looking for?